# how to fill storage parameters?

Tags: smart-contracts, tezos-client, storage, deploy, parameter

I am trying to pass the correct storage parameters in json to be able to deploy my smart contract. Thank you for your attention...

```
      (pair (pair (pair (pair (address %admin) (big_map %ledger nat address))
                  (pair (big_map %metadata string bytes)
                        (big_map %operators (pair address (pair address nat)) unit)))
            (pair (pair (mutez %price) (big_map %reverse_ledger address (list nat)))
                  (pair (string %serial) (nat %token_id))))
      (big_map %token_metadata nat (pair (nat %token_id) (map %token_info string bytes)))) ;
```

What I did (it didn't work):

```
    import {
  Record,
  Address,
  Mutez,
  Nat,
  Big_map,
  String,
  Bytes,
  Map,
  List
} from "@tezwell/michelson-sdk/literal";

const storage = Record(
  {
    admin: Address("tz1i3veHnR4ogcwKmgugcqnunTmTYP8s8ZAr"),
    ledger: Big_map([
      [Nat(1), Address("tz1i3veHnR4ogcwKmgugcqnunTmTYP8s8ZAr")]
    ]),
    metadata: Big_map([
      [
        String(""),
        Bytes(
          "0x68747470733a2f2f676973742e67697468756275736572636f6e74656e742e636f6d2f6f7269616e6131332f36663138333737353065366562383163646434666633363230663738613133322f7261772f653238396663353037326235613931353134383936376239613433333765313835343731363561322f636f6e74726163745f6d6574612e6a736f6e"
        )
      ]
    ]),
    operators: Big_map([]),
    price: Mutez(1),
    reverse_ledger: Big_map([
      [Address("tz1i3veHnR4ogcwKmgugcqnunTmTYP8s8ZAr"), List([Nat(1)])]
    ]),
    serial: String("SERIAL"),
    token_id: Nat(1),
    token_metadata: Big_map([
      [
        Nat(1),
        Record({
          token_id: Nat(1),
          token_info: Map([
            [
              String(""),
              Bytes(
                "0x68747470733a2f2f676973742e67697468756275736572636f6e74656e742e636f6d2f6f7269616e6131332f35313763373231396531383639333938613765666631343335623862653237392f7261772f326337336132613564353365626466313662633864623831643837343236353964323763646462332f6e66745f6d6574612e6a736f6e"
              )
            ]
          ])
        })
      ]
    ])
  },

  [
    [
      [
        ["admin", "ledger"],
        ["metadata"],
      ]],
      [
        ["price", "reverse_ledger"],
        ["serial", "token_id"],
    ],
    [
    "token_metadata"
  ]]
);

console.log("Micheline: ", storage.toMicheline());
console.log("Michelson JSON: ", JSON.stringify(storage.toJSON(), null, 4));
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [michelson-sdk](https://romarq.github.io/michelson-sdk) to generate the Michelson values (Micheline or Michelson JSON).

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-platform-vmrwk1?from-embed=&file=/index.js) (Output can be seen in the console)

**Micheline**

```
    (Pair (Pair (Pair (Pair "tz1i3veHnR4ogcwKmgugcqnunTmTYP8s8ZAr" { Elt 1 "tz1i3veHnR4ogcwKmgugcqnunTmTYP8s8ZAr" }) (Pair { Elt "" 0x68747470733a2f2f676973742e67697468756275736572636f6e74656e742e636f6d2f6f7269616e6131332f36663138333737353065366562383163646434666633363230663738613133322f7261772f653238396663353037326235613931353134383936376239613433333765313835343731363561322f636f6e74726163745f6d6574612e6a736f6e } {  })) (Pair (Pair 1 { Elt "tz1i3veHnR4ogcwKmgugcqnunTmTYP8s8ZAr" { 1 } }) (Pair "SERIAL" 1))) { Elt 1 (Pair 1 { Elt "" 0x68747470733a2f2f676973742e67697468756275736572636f6e74656e742e636f6d2f6f7269616e6131332f35313763373231396531383639333938613765666631343335623862653237392f7261772f326337336132613564353365626466313662633864623831643837343236353964323763646462332f6e66745f6d6574612e6a736f6e }) })
```

**Michelson JSON**

```
{
    "prim": "Pair",
    "args": [
        {
            "prim": "Pair",
            "args": [
                {
                    "prim": "Pair",
                    "args": [
                        {
                            "prim": "Pair",
                            "args": [
                                {
                                    "string": "tz1i3veHnR4ogcwKmgugcqnunTmTYP8s8ZAr"
                                },
                                [
                                    {
                                        "prim": "Elt",
                                        "args": [
                                            {
                                                "int": "1"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "string": "tz1i3veHnR4ogcwKmgugcqnunTmTYP8s8ZAr"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "prim": "Pair",
                            "args": [
                                [
                                    {
                                        "prim": "Elt",
                                        "args": [
                                            {
                                                "string": ""
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "bytes": "68747470733a2f2f676973742e67697468756275736572636f6e74656e742e636f6d2f6f7269616e6131332f36663138333737353065366562383163646434666633363230663738613133322f7261772f653238396663353037326235613931353134383936376239613433333765313835343731363561322f636f6e74726163745f6d6574612e6a736f6e"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ],
                                []
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "prim": "Pair",
                    "args": [
                        {
                            "prim": "Pair",
                            "args": [
                                {
                                    "int": "1"
                                },
                                [
                                    {
                                        "prim": "Elt",
                                        "args": [
                                            {
                                                "string": "tz1i3veHnR4ogcwKmgugcqnunTmTYP8s8ZAr"
                                            },
                                            [
                                                {
                                                    "int": "1"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "prim": "Pair",
                            "args": [
                                {
                                    "string": "SERIAL"
                                },
                                {
                                    "int": "1"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        [
            {
                "prim": "Elt",
                "args": [
                    {
                        "int": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "prim": "Pair",
                        "args": [
                            {
                                "int": "1"
                            },
                            [
                                {
                                    "prim": "Elt",
                                    "args": [
                                        {
                                            "string": ""
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "bytes": "68747470733a2f2f676973742e67697468756275736572636f6e74656e742e636f6d2f6f7269616e6131332f35313763373231396531383639333938613765666631343335623862653237392f7261772f326337336132613564353365626466313662633864623831643837343236353964323763646462332f6e66745f6d6574612e6a736f6e"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hello Rodrigo, sorry to bother you again but I have a problem with a new storage return, I would like to know how you did to fill in the parameters correctly I tried to base myself on your answer to adapt my new storage but I don't can't do it, I'm updating the question with my new storage

Comment: Updated the answer above